# How to get a React Project running in Docker?

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, development-environment

I'm trying to run my react project locally with Docker. Here are the configurations and folder structure of my project

```
  |- public
  | |- index.html
  |- src
  | |- Routes.jsx #can it be because this is not App.js?
  | |- index.js
  |- docker-compose.yml
  |- Dockerfile
  ...
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  react-dev:
    container_name: sample_container
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    volumes:
      - ".:/app"
      - "/app/node_modules"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY yarn.lock /app/yarn.lock
RUN yarn install --silent
RUN yarn add react-scripts@3.0.1 -g --silent
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY . /app
RUN yarn
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

I get the successfully build and successfully tagged along with the "Project is running at http....."
but when I visit the link, my project is not rendered. I'm sure I am missing something in my Dockerfile for it not to run properly...

Comment: I think you need to specify network for container, to tell docker that container is using connection with your local machine. Then you'll be able to connect to your containers port

Comment: Do I need to specify this is the Dockerfile? On my first docker compose build,  docker did ask to access my windows computer drive. Is this what you're referring too?

Comment: No. I was thinking about https://docs.docker.com/network/. I'm not an docker expert, but I think that you need at least one bridge network to connect internal docker network to your machine. Without it container is isolated.

Comment: You mentioned that you visited the link. But this link was made by app inside the container. For example `The application is now running on http://localhost:3000`, 3000 is a port inside the container. And you mount it on 3001 port on your machine. Maybe thats the case?

Comment: @VictorTrusov Ah I see it now. I'm very new to Docker... so in the docker-compose.yml - the line ports: - "3001:3000" is mounting the container port 3000 to my localhost port 3001. it does work now at localhost:3001. Thank you :)

Comment: Cool :) post it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that you visited the link. But that link was made by app **inside** the container.

For example `The application is now running on http://localhost:3000`, 3000 - is a port inside the container. And you mounted it on 3001 port on your machine:

```
# docker-compose.yml

ports:
  - "3001:3000"
```

So the correct link is `http://localhost:3001`